# What is the right way for creating conditional forms in ASP.Net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**Overview of the problem:**

I want to have some conditional logic in my form. The user makes a choice with a radio button and depending on the selection I want to hide some fields and show some other fields. This should also affect validation (hidden fields shouldn't be validated). I think this is a typical problem, but I couldn't find any examples and my own solution seems to have a lot of plumbing.

**My actual problem:**

Let's start with the viewmodel classes (somewhat simplified for the needs of this question):

```
public class Scenario
{
   public Request Request { get; set; }
   public Response Response { get; set; }
   // … some other properties
}

public class Request
{
   //some properties
}

public class Response
{
    [Required]
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NotZero] //this is my custom validation attribute
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public string ErrorDescr { get; set; }
}
```

In my create/edit view for the `Scenario` model I have a rather big form consisting of 3 tabs. On the 3rd tab I display a partial view based on the `Response` model. This is where I want the conditional logic. `ResponseType` property is the radio button on the form. It can have two values: NORMAL and ERROR. In the case of ERROR I want to display and validate `ErrorCode` and `ErrorDescr` properties. In the case of NORMAL I want to display and validate only the `State` property.

**My solution:**

1. In the Response partial view I have some jquery .hide() and .show() calls hooked up to hide/show relevant input elements.
2. I modified jquery unobtrusive validation script to stop it from validating hidden fields ( http://blog.waynebrantley.com/2011/01/mvc3-validates-hidden-fields-using.html )
3. In the Scenario controller I have code like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult Edit(int id, Scenario scenario)
   {
      Response response=scenario.Response;
      if (response.ResponseType != null)
      {
         if (response.ResponseType == "NORMAL")
         {
            //in this case remove validation for errorcode
            this.ModelState.Remove("Response.ErrorCode");
         }
         else
         {
            //in this case remove validation for state
            this.ModelState.Remove("Response.State");
         }
      }
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          //map to entity and save to database
      }
   }
   ```

This is a whole lot of ugly plumbing (especially the controller code - removing items from ModelState with a string key... no type safety etc), **surely there must be a better way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite old now and I don't like this hanging around without an answer so I'll answer it myself.

The correct solution is to implement a custom validation attribute and also implement the IClientValidatable interface. This satisfies all the requirements - no plumbing inside the controller and consistent client side validation.

Nowadays I probably wouldn't even implement this myself - I would use an existing library like [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) which provides a nice and flexible RequiredIf attribute:

```
public class Response
{
    [Required]
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("ResponseType == 'NORMAL'"]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("ResponseType == 'ERROR'"]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public string ErrorDescr { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute works both on server side and on client side once you configure it by adding a few lines to Global.asax and including a javascript with the validators. You can read the details on the project page.

Answer (score 1):

You might try inheriting from `IValidateableObject` in your `Response` class and performing the conditional validation in `Validate`. Like so:

```
public class Response : IValidateableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }   
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescr { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ResponseType == "NORMAL")
        {
            if (State.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
                yield return new ValidationResult("State is required", new [] { "State" });
        }

        // additional validations...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately validations made in this way don't work on the client side. I really don't like that because it introduces a two-phase validation effect (the user fills the form correctly according to client-side validation, submits the form, and hey, he gets some new errors back... bad user experience).